# Unexpectedly finding nil, even after unwrapping

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

In my UITableViewController, I have an optional property which is a `CNContact`. If not nil, I want to populate some text fields with the contact's data.

Here is the property:

```
var contact: CNContact? = nil {
    didSet {
        if contact != nil {
            prefillFromContact(contact!)
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code setting a text field

```
func prefillFromContact(con: CNContact) {
    print(con.givenName)
    firstNameTextField.text = con.givenName
}
```

The print statement works, and returns the contact's name, but the following line throws an error.

```
Kate
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I can't work out why it works on the print statement, but not the following line.

Comment: Have you created the reference to your `firstNameTextField` IBOutlet in your xib/storyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume `firstNameTextField` is declared as an implicit optional, like this:

```
var firstNameTextField: UITextField!
```

And you are causing this code to be called before `viewDidLoad`.

If so, `firstNameTextField` is nil.  It is only possible to set the values of UIViews loaded from XIB/Storyboards once they are loaded.  Before that, their outlets are nil.

As an aside (even though this isn't what is causing your problem):

```
if contact != nil {
     prefillFromContact(contact!)
}
```

is more Swifty like this:

```
if let contact = contact { 
     // this is only true if contact != nil, and you have a contact variable
     // that is of type CNContact, not CNContact?
     prefillFromContact(contact)
}
```

Comment: Ah of course. Yeah I'm setting the `contact` property in the `prepareForSegue` before this VC. I moved the `prefillFromContact` into `viewDidLoad` and it's working great. Thanks for the aside too!